# Error of midpoint, trapezoidal and simpson rule in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm writing a script to numerically find the integral using these three methods. Right now I can compute the right value for the integral, but I need also to print the error and the  upper analytical bound of it. I have no idea how to do that in matlab. From the formulas I need to find the maximal value of f'' and f'''', but I dont know ho to do that. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide code of what you try ? And explain more what part doesn't work ?

Comment: Hi the problem is that I didn't implemented nothing to find the error, since I'm not sure how to compute it. As said my problem is that I don't know how to compute the error between my result and the exact integral and I don't know how to compute the upper bound of the error (the formula that I have is -(f''(c)*(b - a)*h^2)/12).

Comment: I can say that I need the exact integral of the function in the given intervall in order to compute the error (abs(approximation - real)) and I need a way to find the maximal value of f'' to compute te bound

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the upper bound of the error for either the trapezoidal rule, Simpson's rule or midpoint rule on `f(x)` **must** be bound between the interval of `x in [a,b]` or else we won't be able to find this error.  I have two solutions for you, depending on what has been given.

## Solution #1 - Closed form solution to f(x) is given

If you have a closed form solution of the integral, use the symbolic toolbox in MATLAB to first define your `f(x)`, then use the `diff` command to differentiate to find `f'(x)`.  If you want the second derivative, apply another `diff` command to it.

Example:

```
syms x; 
f = x^4;
df = diff(f);
d2f = diff(df);

f =

x^4

df =

4*x^3

d2f =

12*x^2
```

If you want to find the maximum within a certain interval, assuming a step size `T` between the lower bound `a` and `b`, you can try doing:

```
a = 1;
b = 3;
T = 0.01;
maxf = max(abs(double(subs(f,a:T:b))));

maxf = 

81
```

What the above code does is that it finds the maximum value between `[1,3]` of `x^4` in a step size of `T = 0.01`.  You can replace the fourth line's first parameter `f` with whatever function you want.  *Note:* The error terms require the **absolute* value, which is why the `abs` function is there.

## Solution #2 - Closed form solution to f(x) is not given

If you **don't** have the function, but you only have a set of `(x,y)` pairs, you can still use the `diff` function on the output `y` values but it will implement the **discrete** approximation to the derivative.  As such, the derivative is approximately equal to:

```
x_i' = x_{i+1} - x_i
```

This takes the `(i+1)` point and subtracts it with the `i` point.  If you apply `diff` on an array of `N` points, it will return an array of `N-1` points to accommodate for looking one sample ahead to find the difference.  After, you can use this array and find the maximum of the derivative.  If you want to find the maximum of the second derivative, simply call `diff` again on the first outpt of `diff`.  Example to get you started:

```
x = 0:0.01:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
ymax = max(abs(diff(y)));

ymax =

    0.0100
```

What the above does is that it finds the **maximum value of the discrete approximation to the derivative** to `y = sin(x)`, as denoted by `diff(y)`.

Hopefully one of these will work for you!

## Aside

I used to teach numerical methods back when I was an instructor at my university.  Take a look at these slides for a good intro to numerical integration using Simpson's Rule and the Trapezoidal Rule.  There are also slides on how to code this in MATLAB (without using any built-in functions), as well as some slides on how to compute the error, and how many points you need within a fixed interval to guarantee a particular approximation error.

http://www.rnet.ryerson.ca/~rphan/mth510/f2012/Lab_10/MTH510F2012_Lab10.pdf